# The number of positive integer solutions to the equation $x_1+2x_2+...+nx_n=n^2.$

Tags: combinatorics, inequality, diophantine-equations

> Let $n \ge 2, n \in \mathbb N$. $A_n$ denotes the number of positive integer solutions to the equation
>   $$x_1+2x_2+...+nx_n=n^2.$$
>   Prove inequality
>   $$\frac{n^n(n-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}\left(n!\right)^2}<A_n<\frac{n^{2n-1}}{\left(n!\right)^2}$$

*I have no idea how to solve this problem.*

Comment: May I ask what methods have you tried?

Comment: @the4seasons: No methods. I do not know how to solve. Tried $n=2$ and $n = 3$

Comment: This is [OEIS sequence A107379](https://oeis.org/A107379).

Comment: We have:
$$ A_n = [x^{n^2}]\frac{x}{1-x}\cdot\frac{x^2}{1-x^2}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{x^n}{1-x^n} \tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ A_n = [x^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}]\frac{1}{1-x}\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^2}\cdot\ldots\cdot\frac{1}{1-x^n}\tag{2}$$ and the main contribute comes from the pole at $x=1$.

Comment: where is from this problem?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio:[Here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2053319/number-of-solutions-of-x-12x-2-cdotskx-k-n) I have a similar problem. Can you help me to solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $A_n$ is also equal to the number of tuples $(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ such that $0<y_1<y_2< \ldots y_n$ and $y_1+\ldots +y_n=n^2$.

[Consider the bijection $y_1=x_n,y_2=x_n+x_{n-1}$,$\ldots$,$y_n=x_n+\ldots +x_1$.]

The number of such tuples is less than $\dfrac{1}{n!}$ times the number of positive integer solutions to $z_1+\ldots +z_n=n^2$, which is ${n^2-1 \choose n-1}$, which is at most $\dfrac{n^{2(n-1)}}{(n-1)!}=\dfrac{n^{2n-1}}{n!}$—this gives the upper bound.

No time for the lower bound now.

Comment: I took the liberty to fix a possible typo.  I hope you wouldn't mind.

Answer (score 2):

From the OP's question [The number of positive integer solutions to the equation $x_1+x_2+...+x_n=n^2.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1842357/the-number-of-positive-integer-solutions-to-the-equation-x-1x-2-x-n-n2), we have 
$$A_n>\frac{1}{2^{n-1}n!}\,\binom{n^2-1}{n-1}\geq\frac{\big(n(n-1)\big)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}n!(n-1)!}=\frac{n^n(n-1)^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}(n!)^2}\,.$$